# How to fetch the path for the spring-logback from the Database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging, spring-logback

I recently started working in a Spring boot project. Here all the application or environment level properties are stored in the DB (Oracle). This includes all the URLs, paths etc used in the application.

These properties are fetched at the startup, stored in a static map and then used across the entire application (perhaps the idea is that the client can update any property in DB and restart the particular environment and all should work fine).

This works fine accept the fact that the path for server logs is still picked from a `logging.properties` file. The logging is done via spring-logback xml configuration.

I believe that the logging is the first thing done by the Spring boot even before  the DB connections and hence it is difficult to fetch the path from DB and then provide it to the logback file.

Is there any possible way to configure the logging so that the path for the logs can be picked up from the DB as well.

Answer (score 0):

I cerebrate you require to store the application.properties file data into the DB.
you can configure this and if you optate to store the appication.properties into DB withal you can do that by utilizing the DB appender.

```
<configuration  debug="true">

  <appender name="DB" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender">
     <connectionSource class="ch.qos.logback.core.db.DataSourceConnectionSource">

       <dataSource class="${dataSourceClass}">
         <!-- Joran cannot substitute variables
         that are not attribute values. Therefore, we cannot
         declare the next parameter like the others. 
         -->
         <param name="${url-key:-url}" value="${url_value}"/>
         <serverName>${serverName}</serverName>
         <databaseName>${databaseName}</databaseName>
       </dataSource>

       <user>${user}</user>
       <password>${password}</password>
     </connectionSource>
  </appender>

  <root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="DB" />
  </root>  
</configuration>
```

But need to take the data from DB then you can utilize the below code.

```
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.core.env.ConfigurableEnvironment;
import org.springframework.core.env.MapPropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.MutablePropertySources;
import org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource;

public class ReadDBPropertiesInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReadDBPropertiesInitializer.class);

    /**
     * Name of the custom property source added by this post processor class
     */
    private static final String PROPERTY_SOURCE_NAME = "databaseProperties";

    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {

        ConfigurableEnvironment configEnv = ((ConfigurableEnvironment) applicationContext.getEnvironment());

        LOG.info("Load properties from database");

        Map<String, Object> propertySource = new HashMap<>();

        try {

            final String url = getEnv(configEnv, "spring.datasource.url");

            String driverClassName = getProperty(configEnv, "spring.datasource.driver-class-name");

            final String username = getEnv(configEnv, "spring.datasource.username");
            final String password = getEnv(configEnv, "spring.datasource.password");

            DataSource ds = DataSourceBuilder.create().url(url).username(username).password(password)
                    .driverClassName(driverClassName).build();

            // Fetch all properties
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = ds.getConnection()
                    .prepareStatement("SELECT config_key as name, config_value as value, config_label as label FROM TB_CONFIGURATION");

            ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

            // Populate all properties into the property source
            while (rs.next()) {             
                final String propName = rs.getString("name");
                final String propValue = rs.getString("value");
                final String propLabel = rs.getString("label");
                LOG.info(String.format("Property: %s | Label: %s", propName, propLabel));
                LOG.info(String.format("Value: %s", propValue));
                propertySource.put(propName, propValue);
            }

            // Create a custom property source with the highest precedence and add it to
            // Spring Environment
            applicationContext.getEnvironment().getPropertySources()
                    .addFirst(new MapPropertySource(PROPERTY_SOURCE_NAME, propertySource));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error fetching properties from db");
        }

    }

    private String getEnv(ConfigurableEnvironment configEnv, final String property) {
        MutablePropertySources propertySources = configEnv.getPropertySources();
        PropertySource<?> appConfigProp = propertySources.get("applicationConfigurationProperties");
        return System.getenv().get(((String) appConfigProp.getProperty(property)).replace("${", "").replace("}", ""));
    }

    private String getProperty(ConfigurableEnvironment configEnv, final String property) {
        MutablePropertySources propertySources = configEnv.getPropertySources();
        PropertySource<?> appConfigProp = propertySources.get("applicationConfigurationProperties");
        return (String) appConfigProp.getProperty(property);
    }
```

Comment: Hi. This is a good solution for general properties. This is similar to what we have currently implemented for other properties. But this doesn't work for properties like the path for server logs; because that path is needed prior to DB connection itself.

Comment: Hi Path for server log nothing but value. And value you can take from a property file.
it's looks akin to below. 
Hi Path for server log nothing but value. And value you can take from a property file. it's looks akin to below.

server.log: the server path.